# Beginners Ubuntu linux guide for experienced windows developer

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am an windows developer with over 15 years experience. I have just started looking at the latest version of Ubuntu Linux. Could someone point me at a good beginners guide to Ubuntu (preferably from a developers prospective) which is aimed at a Windows user? I have found several using google, but unfortunately I know so little on this subject I can't tell a good guide from a bad one. I have version 10.04 LTS.

Comment: I think you might want to make your question a bit more specific. Why are you asking about Ubuntu in particular? Unless you're trying to work on Debian/Ubuntu-specific applications (i.e. a few core things like aptitude), I'd guess it's because you want to develop Linux applications, using Ubuntu for your environment? So are you asking about getting Ubuntu set up as a development environment? Or maybe I'm way off and you really just want to know about developing for Linux.

Comment: It might be worth visiting: ubuntu.stackexchange.com (now public-beta), or unix.stackexchange.com (public-beta in 3 days) for answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux world is much more fragmented than the Windows world; for developing GUI programs, there's several GUI toolkits to choose from (GTK and QT are the two most popular; there's also FLTK, TK, and even old Motif is still kicking around).

Systems programming is thankfully MUCH better, buy a copy of [Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment, Second Edition](http://www.apuebook.com/) and you'll have enough to write great systems tools on dozens of platforms.

If you're in the middle-layers somewhere, a higher level than systems programming, you'll typically be working with other libraries and toolkits: Apache, PostgreSQL, Hadoop, libevent, Tomcat, Ruby on Rails, Django, expat, GnuTLS, OpenSSL, Perl, Python, Ruby, Erlang, etc. Figuring out *which* of the options you've got to work with may be daunting, but most projects have reasonable documentation.

Most tools have manpages: skim `man man`, and then: `man 1 intro`, `man 2 intro`, `man 3 intro`, `man 4 intro`, `man 5 intro`, `man 7 intro`, `man 8 intro`. (Feel free to look at `man 6 intro` if you want, but manual section 6 is for games.) `1` is for user-commands, `2` for system calls, `3` for library calls, `4` for device files, `5` for configuration files, `7` for "frameworks" (`socket(7)` and `ip(7)` for socket and IP details), `8` for system administration commands.

Maybe asking for specific advice would lead to more concrete answers -- the simple truth is there's no simple single programming guide on Linux systems.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out http://www.wiki.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Above link failed - but http://wiki.ubuntu.com/ works

Answer (score 1):

Some might argue that learning specifically a distribution of Linux is counter-intuitive to the whole 'Linux mindset.' I'm afraid I can't answer your question specifically in terms of good guide resources, but I've found in my quest to learn something new, a place to be able to *ask questions* is more important than an all-inclusive tome. To that end, I would also recommend http://ubuntuforums.org/ - it will give you a chance to clarify anything that any tomes couldn't answer.

I might also suggest to forget everything you know about Windows when learning. With fifteen years under your belt, I'm sure you're an experienced Windows developer. There are a lot of things that will transfer nicely, like good coding practices, and there are a some things which may seem (or even be) counter-intuitive. If you learn to take these in your stride and accept you're learning and not failing, an install of Ubuntu and a desire to learn will do you better than any Ubuntu tome.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) has a lot of good info where you also can ask specific questions for ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Programming for some ideas

But for us to be more helpful you need to decide What exactly are you looking to develop? For example is it a C#, C++, or java application? is it a desktop, mobile, or web application?

There are different tools for different projects.

Going by your previous questions I'd think your a C# programmer so I'd have a look at the [mono project](http://monodevelop.com/)